# Photoshop SDK: is it possible to create a plugin that is shown as a layer in the layer-manager?

Tags: c++, plugins, photoshop

Before I start diggin' into the *Photoshop SDK*, I want to make sure what I'm aiming for is possible. My general Idea was to create a plugin that is shown **as a layer in the layer-manager** and renders clones of a layer that the user can specifiy, based on parameters of course.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Look at what Adobe calls Smart Objects.  They appear as layers but actually represent data from "outside" sources (whether they could easily be made to represent data from other layers in the same document, I don't know).